# Count duplicates in a linking table

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates

I have three tables:

```
contacts
brands
contact_brands      // linking table
```

For the purposes of my question, we'll only deal with the UID columns within these (`contact_id` and `brand_id`).

`contact_brands` is a linking table, containing pairs of `contact_id` and `brand_id`, and I need to find all **duplicate** pairings within it (i.e. `contact_id`s that have the same `brand_id` assigned more than once).

I'm almost certain I need a `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM...) AS...`-style query, and almost certainly a `COUNT()` within there too, but my knowledge is coming up blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the duplicates just by using `group by`:

```
select contact_id, brand_id, count(*) as cnt
from contact_brands
group by contact_id, brand_id
having cnt > 1;
```

If you like, you can join back to get the original rows.

If your linking table only has these two columns, then you have a challenge dealing with the duplicates.  This would have been solved using an auto-incremented id, which you can now add if you like.  Otherwise, you should have a unique constraint or index on `contact_brands(contact_id, brand_id)` to prevent duplicates.

Comment: That's excellent, thanks. Turned out to be a lot simpler than I anticipated.